# javascript unhide an applet inside an iframe

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, iframe, applet

okay what i'm trying to do is make it so the applet inside the iframe is displyed cause i have the style set to display:none for the applet, The iframe to displayed at all times, the iframe is inside a popup, this popup is called with javascript aswell, what i wanna do is when the user calls the popup it also displays the applet, then when they close the popup it makes the applet dissapear, here is what ive tryed

it calls the popup, everything works, it displays the iframe, but inside that iframe theres the applet the display is set to none, i need to make it display the applet when they call the popup,

```
    <script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.playhighpopup').each(function() {
       var hiddenSection = $('section.hiddenplay_high');
      var hiddenapplet = $('section.hiddenplay_high.iframe.applet');
                hiddenapplet.show();
                hiddenSection.fadeIn(1000)
                    // unhide section.hidden
                    .css({ 'display':'block' })
                    // set to full screen
                    .css({ width: $(window).width() + 'px', height: $(window).height() + 'px' })
                    .css({ top:($(window).height() - hiddenSection.height())/2 + 'px', 
                        left:($(window).width() - hiddenSection.width())/2 + 'px' })
                    // greyed out background
                    .css({ 'background-color': 'rgba(0,0,0,0.7)' })
                    .appendTo('body');
                    $('span.close').click(function(){ $(hiddenSection).fadeOut(1000); $('applet').hide(); });

    });
});
</script>
```

i can make the applet display without the iframe, but i need the iframe cause the applet flickers from some of the ajax features on my website, the iframe stops the flickering.

Comment: Try this, hiddenapplet.css("visibility", 'visible');

Answer (score 1):

> ..style set to `display:none` for the applet

That is most likely the problem.  [According to the W3C](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/display#Values):

> This value causes an element to **not appear** in the document. ..

Typically that means it is not included in the DOM at all.

Try it instead with `visibility: hidden` or `collapse`.  See [more on `visibility`](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/visibility).